# SG cluster installation

Tags: cluster

I'm having a problem when trying to run the package (service guard cluster)
cmrunpkg -n

bellow the log file telling me the error:

```
    Mounting /dev/vg01/lvol01 at /example
mount: special device /dev/vg01/lvol01 does not exist
Jan 29 20:51:06 root@<servername>[4361]: ERROR: Function sg_check_and_mount
Jan 29 20:51:06 root@<servername> filesystem.sh[4361]: ERROR: Failed to mount /dev/vg01/lvol01
```

I have the following but keep saying I cant mount

```
--- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/vg01/lvol01
  LV Name                lvol01
  VG Name                vg01
  LV UUID                xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time servername.net, 2021-01-29 02:48:37 +0000
  LV Status              NOT available
  LV Size                <200.00 GiB
  Current LE             51199
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto

[root@server conf]# mount /dev/vg01/lvol01 /example
mount: special device /dev/vg01/lvol01 does not exist
[root@server conf]#


df -h
Filesystem                   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                     3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                        3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                        3.9G  9.0M  3.9G   1% /run
tmpfs                        3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/vg00-root        4.0G   69M  4.0G   2% /
/dev/mapper/vg00-usr         8.0G  2.1G  6.0G  26% /usr
/dev/mapper/vg00-opt         4.0G  654M  3.4G  16% /opt
/dev/mapper/vg00-var         8.0G  261M  7.8G   4% /var
/dev/mapper/vg00-tmp         2.0G   35M  2.0G   2% /tmp
/dev/mapper/vg00-home        2.0G   37M  2.0G   2% /home
/dev/mapper/vg00-var_crash   8.0G   33M  8.0G   1% /var/crash
/dev/mapper/vg00-opt_mcafee  3.0G   71M  3.0G   3% /opt/McAfee
/dev/mapper/vg00-opt_nessus  4.0G  953M  3.1G  24% /opt/nessus_agent
/dev/mapper/vg00-var_mcafee 1014M   61M  954M   6% /var/McAfee
/dev/sda1                   1014M  154M  861M  16% /boot
tmpfs                        783M     0  783M   0% /run/user/124100805
```

Comment: If I had to guess, I would say that you followed instructions a little too closely and the computer is telling you that you don’t have a volume group mounted at `/dev/vg01/lvol01` 

Comment: I add some lines above how can I mount the volume group I'm so confuse

Comment: What does `df -h` show?

Comment: I just add into the post df -h Thank you Matigo if you can help me ..